# Asp.Net-Core pass JavaScript function to partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Using asp.net-core I made a "PopUp.cshtml" file:

```
<div class="popUpDeleteBackground" hidden>
    <div class="popUpDelete">
        <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
        <p>This action is irreversible</p>
        <div class="popUpDeleteButtonDiv">
            <button class="btn deleteConfirm">JA</button>
            <button class="btn" onclick="PopUpRemove()">NEE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function PopUpShow(licensePlate) {
        $(".popUpDeleteBackground").attr("hidden", false);

        $(".deleteConfirm").on("click", () => {
            Delete(licensePlate);
            PopUpRemove();
        });
    }
    function PopUpRemove() {
        $(".popUpDeleteBackground").attr("hidden", true);
    }
</script>
```

I want this popup partial to be used in multiple pages of the website. The problem is that the delete functions are different for each page.
So my question is: Is there a way to pass a JavaScript function to a partial view?

What I've tried so far is passing a string with `@await Html.PartialAsync("_ConfirmPopUp", "functionToRun()");` and then tried to run it with `<script>@Model</script>`.
But I got an error message in the console saying: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `functionToRun()` as a string to the Model of the view. Instead just pass the name of the function without the parenthesis - `functionToRun`.

Then in the code dont write `<script>@Model</script>`. Instead just put the name of the calling function dynamically when the page loads like this:

```
<script>
    function PopUpShow(licensePlate) {
        $(".popUpDeleteBackground").attr("hidden", false);

        $(".deleteConfirm").on("click", () => {
            //Delete(licensePlate);
            @string.Format("{0}();", Model)
            PopUpRemove();
        });
    }
    function PopUpRemove() {
        $(".popUpDeleteBackground").attr("hidden", true);
    }
</script>
```

This will render the name of the function that would be called on click of the `.deleteConfirm` element. Note the `@string.Format("{0}();", Model)` code instead of the `Delete` function call.

Comment: I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" when using ```<text>@Model + "();"</text>```.

Comment: I have updated the code. This is a cleaner version and less error-prone.